# Decorator pattern issue - how to call nested decorators methods?

Tags: oop, object, design-patterns, nested, decorator

I'm now studying the decorator pattern, here some example code (PHP) :

```
abstract class component{

  public function drawShape(){};

}

class concreteComponent extends component{

   public function drawShape(){//code};

}

class decoratorComponent extends component{

  private $component;

  public function __construct($component){ $this->component=$component; }

  public function drawShape(){

      $this->component->drawShape();

  }

}

class borderDecorator extends decoratorComponent{

  public function drawShape(){

    $this->drawBorder();
    $this->component->drawShape();

  }

  public function setBorder(){};
  public function drawBorder(){};

}

class bgColorDecorator extends decoratorComponent{

  public function drawShape(){

    $this->drawBgColor();
    $this->component->drawShape();

  }

  public function setbgColor(){};
  public function drawBgColor(){};

}
```

Ok, now:

```
$test=new concreteComponent();
$border=new borderDecorator($test);
$border->setBorder(10);
$bgColor= new bgColorDecorator($border);
$bgColor->setBgColor(#000);
```

Now I have a component decorated with a #000 bg color and a 10(some unit) border.

With

```
$bgColor->drawShape();
```

it means `drawBgColor` + `drawBorder` + `drawShape` and all right, BUT:

How can I modify or remove the border??

```
$bgColor-> ???
```

The bgColor class can't access directly the border methods...

Thanks

Comment: Mhm I'm studying from a book, you can look at It like interfaces, so I have the same method drawShape() and I can call it no worry if I'm using a decorated component or not (am I right?) @PeeHaa

Comment: If your object graph is not too complex, just reconstruct the whole graph from scratch when the decorators are changing. However, if that's too much overhead you may write a decorator that is aware of other features or plugins. Something like `$test = new ConcreteCmp(); $pluggableCmp = new PluggableDecorator($test); $pluggableCmp.addFeature(new BorderFeature()); $pluggableCmp.addFeature(new BGColorFeature())`

Comment: And then from $pluggableCmp how can I call the methods of BorderFeature or BGColorFeature to modify them? @plalx

Comment: Not sure what you mean... $pluggableCmp would hold an internal list of features. You most choose the most appropriate strategy to track the features. If only one may exist per type then perhaps store them in a map. You may also decide that a feature is identifiable by it's type and attributes and treat it as a value. Therefore, you could `$pluggableCmp.addFeature(new Border(black))` and do `$pluggableCmp.removeFeature(new Border(black))`. Modifying a feature would just be removing it and adding it back with a different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have chained your decorators in a way that leaves out a bgColorDecorator instance from which you cannot set/remove the borders.

What you should do is to **change the order of construct** and finish by the borderDecorator part :

```
$test=new concreteComponent();

$bgColor= new bgColorDecorator($test); // pass test to bgcolor
$bgColor->setBgColor(#000);

$border=new borderDecorator($bgColor); // pass bgcolor to border
$border->setBorder(10);

// You can now set/remove border on $border
// and of course : $border->drawShape();
```

It seems that your task is to render an object so the proper order of drawing should necessitate a change in your drawShape methods to keep the order background / shape / border

```
$this->drawBgColor();
$this->component->drawShape();
// will become a post-action
$this->component->drawShape();    
$this->drawBgColor();
```

The problem is now **you won't be able to set the backgroundcolor dynamically for the same reason**. So the other solution could be to modify your decoratorComponent interface to include what you need and implement it in the decoratorComponent subclasses.

**Edit for double border case :**

Just chain two borderDecorator to a Component

```
$cmp = new concreteComponent();

$bDecrtor1 = new borderDecorator($cmp); // 1st border decorator on cmp
$bDecrtor1 ->setBorder(10);

$bDecrtor2=new borderDecorator($bDecrtor1); // 2nd border decorator on 1st one
$bDecrtor2->setBorder(20);

// $bDecrtor2->drawShape();
// You can then use bDecrtor1 or bDecrtor2 to (re)set the border properties
// You can use bDecrtor2 to chain other decorators...
```

Comment: I don't need that code right now, I was just trying to practicing and then I can't see how decorators can be a flexible solution... (I'm reading a book for OOP)... Decorators should allow me to add/remove actions dynamically and runtime to an object (decorated), but when I add more that one decorator, the decorators I added before the last one become like unusable... If i have 10 decorators I can't every time modify the decoratorComponent interface to add a possible decorator action, that's not the light and flexible logic behind the pattern... @floppy12

Comment: @Francesco It is a flexible solution in the sense that you can chain decorators to your component to build more evolved components and so on, actually the order of chaining will make different behaviors from the same source code. By the way, why don't you use every decorators (not only the latest one) ? You could use each of them to (re)set the desired property

Comment: And in the case I want a double border? I can only use one if I use another borderDecorator to override the first borderDecator... @floppty12

Comment: @Francesco You can chain two borders decorators without implementing a specific "double border" decorator class... Here is the flexibility i'm talking about. See edit for examples.

Comment: Mmh, I still miss how to change the 1st border from the $bDecrtor2 istance... $bDecrtor2->?? @floppy12

Comment: @Francesco You can't unless you keep a reference to bDecrtor1 and 2 ! Just set the right properties and it's done. Now if you want to change (and change again) all properties at run time, You could keep the initial component reference and instanciate new decorators (allowing you to set their properties again) for a temporary use, then everything is "discarded". It has an evident drawback of multiplying your "decorator logic" thoughout your code, but you could wrap it around if needed

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is implement the [magic method](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) named [`__call()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) (a catch-all method), to try to delegate any non-existing method to the wrapped `component`:

```
class decoratorComponent extends component{

  private $component;

  /* ... */

  public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    return call_user_func_array( array( $this->component, $name ), $arguments );
  }
}
```

You'll just have to build in safeguards to catch the cases where the method you're trying to call ultimately doesn't exist in any component down the line.

However, you should probably also evaluate whether it is even desirable to call the decorator methods *after* you have already wrapped them in another decorator.

Comment: I already know the "magic methods" of PHP, but this is a tricky way, I'd have liked to solve that issue just with a logical pattern (independent of specific programming languages)

Comment: @Francesco The thing is that the decorator pattern isn't usually used to add additional methods, that can be called at random, but rather modify behavior of *existing* methods (possibly configurable through constructor arguments). In your case this would mean you'd pass the border size through the constructor of your `borderDecorator`.